# Compute the correlation between the intersection of two timeseries with pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

Considering two timeseries as `pandas.Series`:

`tser_a`:

```
date

2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   50.41
2016-05-26 13:30:00.023   51.96
2016-05-27 13:30:00.030   51.98
2016-05-28 13:30:00.041   52.00
2016-05-29 13:30:00.048   52.01
2016-06-02 13:30:00.049   51.97
2016-06-03 13:30:00.072   52.01
2016-06-04 13:30:00.075   52.10
```

`tser_b`:

```
date

2016-05-24 13:30:00.023   74.41
2016-05-25 13:30:00.023   74.96
2016-05-26 13:30:00.030   74.98
2016-05-27 13:30:00.041   73.00
2016-05-28 13:30:00.048   73.01
2016-05-29 13:30:00.049   73.97
2016-06-02 13:30:00.072   72.01
2016-06-03 13:30:00.075   72.10
```

I would like to calculate the correlation between these two timeseries.

Pandas does offer the `pandas.Series.corr` ([ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html)) function to compute such a value.

```
corr = tser_a.corr(tser_b)
```

#### My doubt:

However, I need to be sure that the correlation takes into account the exact same date for each value, thus considering only the intersection between `tser_a` and `tser_b`.

As pseudocode:

```
if ((tser_a[date_x] IS NOT NIL) AND (tser_b[date_x] IS NOT NIL)):
    then: consider(tser_a[date_x], tser_b[date_x])
else:
    then: skip and go ahead
```

Then:

```
tser_a -> 2016-05-24 13:30:00.023   74.41
tser_b -> 2016-06-04 13:30:00.075   52.10
```

Must be excluded.

Does `pandas.Series.corr` assume this behaviour by default or should I first intersect the two timeseries accoring to the `date`?

Comment: Are you certain that each series has at most one sample per day? If not, what happens if you have several samples a day?

Comment: On that, I am already sure, since for my use case the sampling is made once per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `tser_a.corr(tser_b)` does match the indices. However, since the two data might not have exact same timestamps, you would get unexpected outcome. In stead, you can use `resample` first:

```
tser_a.resample('D').mean().corr(tser_b.resample('D').mean())
# out -0.5522781562573792
```